# Incrementally decrease font-size of nested nodes

Tags: html, css

For indentation, `margin-left` nicely stacks with itself:

```css
div div {
  margin-left: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is the main text. And below is something indented:
  <div>
    This is indented div with 10px margin
    <div>
      and this div get's another 10px, 20px total
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I want to stack font size decrease in a similar fashion:

[image: Small, smaller and smallest font]

Something like this pseuodocode?

```
div div {
  font-size: -=3pt;
}
```

Is something like this real?

Comment: i fixed your typo. Is font-size not fint-size.

Comment: You just should use `em`'s or percentages which will "cascade" if you use for example `0.8em` it will multiply each time you go down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like

```
div { font-size: 85%; }
```

This will make the font decrease by 15% each level.

If you actually want 3pt less than the parent node, you can probably do something like:

```
div { font-size: calc(100% - 3pt); }
```

But I wouldn't recommend it since you'll approach 0pt quickly. [Browser support for `calc`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Comment: you won me by 2 secs!

Comment: Just a thought. Will it not stack multiplicatively (for every combination) rather than linear (for every layer of nodes)?

Comment: With percentage font size you'll end up with geometric progression instead of arithmetic progression :P but by far the best solution.

Comment: No, it's actually linear, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/3n7fryao/. But I expected `n over k` combinational growth instead (specifically `num_parents-1 over 2`).

Comment: @aioobe the calc? That is what not OP wanted to do like -=3pt means decreasing value (i.e. nested div would be decreasing value) not exactly minus 3pt..

Comment: @BhojendraSah This all isn't only about what *I* wanted. Other visitors will come and will seek slightly different solutions.